# error MSB4018 in vs2017: The “SignFile” task failed unexpectedly

Tags: .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have a **ppt2013** plugin solution with vsto, developer machines with vs 2017 installed.When I build, it comes the signFile error. I've installed

```
.Net framework 4.5.1 targeting pack
.Net framework 4.5.1 SDK
.Net framework 4.5.2 targeting pack
.Net framework 4.6 SDK
.Net framework 4.6 targeting pack
.Net framework 4.6.1 targeting pack
.Net framework 4.6.2 SDK
.Net framework 4.6.2 targeting pack
```

Does anyone have a good idea to solve the error?

```
> detail: D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(264,9):
> error MSB4018: The "SignFile" task failed unexpectedly. 8>D:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(264,9):
> error MSB4018: System.InvalidOperationException: Exception of type
> 'System.InvalidOperationException' was thrown. 8>D:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(264,9):
> error MSB4018:    at
> Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.SignFileInternal(X509Certificate2
> cert, Uri timestampUrl, String path, Boolean
> targetFrameworkSupportsSha256, ResourceManager resources) 8>D:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(264,9):
> error MSB4018:    at
> Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.SignFile(String
> certThumbprint, Uri timestampUrl, String path, String
> targetFrameworkVersion) 8>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(264,9):
> error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.SignFile.Execute()
> 8>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(264,9):
> error MSB4018:    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
> 8>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(264,9):
> error MSB4018:    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.The SignFile is not installed correctly.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P69Jf.png)

Double Click SignFile directly to install leads to the issue.Select File in the Project followed the png's guid is right.

Answer (score 0):

What framework does your project target? It seems to be similar issue described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/787).

Please make sure you've installed the corresponding target-framework SDK, also you may need to install the [.Net 4.0 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) and restart PC to build the project again.

In addition: It seems you haven't install .net 4.6.1 SDK, so if possible you may need to install the `.net framework 4.6.1` SDK also. Go `Tools=>Get Tools and Features=>Individual Components` to install the `.net framework 4.6.1` SDK package.

Comment: I have resolved this issue,thank u.The SignFile is not installed correctly

Comment: Glad to know that, you can consider [adding your workaround as self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and mark it to share the useful info to memebers with similar issue :)